# why i have exoplayer 2 error in my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, exoplayer2.x

Sometimes I got this issue on my device. Is it possible to improve somehow? if this error occurs, video can't be played. The video file is not damaged, because e.g. restarting the application easily launches this video file. I also noticed that the problem appears when I run several movies one by one. I'm using [Better Player](https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer) library in Flutter,
thanks

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [576, 1024, 29.967804], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:542)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [576, 1024, 29.967804], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1047)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:604)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1470)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:640)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readToFlagsOnlyBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:994)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:844)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:892)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:467)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       ... 3 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):   Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, error 0xfffffff4
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1876)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1848)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1127)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1040)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5190):       ... 10 more
I/flutter ( 5190): error found in video with buffer = 10 and id = 10
I/flutter ( 5190): {exception: Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [576, 1024, 29.967804], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES}
E/flutter ( 5190): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [576, 1024, 29.967804], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?